# Filter list of lists based on another list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to filter a list of lists based on the values of another list of lists in Python.

For example, I have:

```
list1 = [[0,1,2],[0,2,3]]
list2 = [['a','b','c'],['a','b','b']]
```

and want to filter `list1` so that it only contains values at the same indexes as 'a' in `list2`. So my desired result is

```
filteredList_a = [[0],[0]]
```

Similarly, filtering `list1` to have only values at the same indexes as 'b' in `list2` would give

```
filteredList_b = [[1],[2,3]]
```

I know how to do this for a single list,

```
>>> list1 = [0,1,2]
>>> list2 = ['a','a','b']
>>> [i for index, i in enumerate(list1) if list2[index] == 'a']
[0,1]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an extension of your list comprehension approach with nested list comprehensions and `zip` to avoid indexes:

```
def filter_by(a, b, target):
    return [[i for i, j in zip(x, y) if j == target] for x, y in zip(a, b)]


list1 = [[0,1,2],[0,2,3]]
list2 = [['a','b','c'],['a','b','b']]
print(filter_by(list1, list2, 'a'))
print(filter_by(list1, list2, 'b'))
```

Output:

```
[[0], [0]]
[[1], [2, 3]]
```

[Try it!](https://repl.it/repls/EmptyAdmiredServer)